# How do I deal with multiple spaces before or in between the words in CS50's initials (more comfortable)?

Tags: c, cs50

Problem: http://docs.cs50.net/problems/initials/more/initials.html
As I said in the title, I can't seem to get the program to output the initials with no spaces if the user inputs extra spaces before the name or inputs extra spaces between the first and last name.

Right now, it works only if I input my name like:First Last with no spaces before the name and only one space inbetween the two words. It will print out FL without any additional spaces. I want it to do this no matter how many extra spaces I have before or inbetween the first and last name.

My current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Name: ");
    string s = get_string();

    printf("%c", toupper(s[0]));

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {
        if (s[i] == ' ') {
            printf("%c", toupper(s[i +1]));
        }
}

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: One way to do it is to use a variable to hold the previous character. If the previous character was a space and the current character is not a space, then output the current character as uppercase.

Comment: There's a [cs50 stack exchange](http://cs50.stackexchange.com/) if you're interested.

Answer (score 2):

While you already have a good answer, presuming that `string s = get_string();` in the `cs50.h` world just fills `s` with a *nul-terminated* string, and `s` is either a *character array* or *pointer to allocated memory* there are a couple of areas where you may consider improvements.

First, don't use `printf` to print a single character. That is what `putchar` (or `fputc`) is for. (granted a smart optimizing compiler should do it for you, but don't rely on the compiler to fix inefficiencies for you) E.g., instead of

```
printf("%c", toupper(s[0]));
```

simply

```
putchar (toupper(s[0]));
```

Also, there are some logic issues you may wish to consider. What you want to know is (1) "*Is the current character a letter?*" (e.g. `isalpha (s[x])`, (2) "*Is this the first character (e.g. index `0`), or is it a character that follows a space?*" (e.g. `s[x-1] == ' '`). With than information, you can use a single `putchar` to output the initials.

Further, with `s` being a string, you can simply use *pointer arithmetic* (e.g. `while (*s) {.. do stuff with *s ..; s++;}`) which ends when you reach the *nul-terminator*, or if you want to preserve `s` as a pointer to the first character, or if it is an *array*, then `char *p = s;` and operate on `p`)

Putting those pieces together, you could do something like the following without relying on `string.h` (you can use simple `if`s and bit manipulations of the 6th bit to remove reliance on `ctype.h` functions as well -- that's for later):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (void) {

    char *p = NULL;

    printf ("Name: ");
    string s = get_string();    /* assuming this works as it appears */

    for (p = s; *p; p++)
        /* if current is [a-zA-Z] and (first or follows space) */
        if (isalpha (*p) && (p == s || (*(p - 1) == ' ')))
            putchar (toupper (*p));

    putchar ('\n');    /* tidy up */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/initials
Name: David C. Rankin
DCR

$ ./bin/initials
Name: Jane Doe
JD

$ ./bin/initials
Name: d
D

$ ./bin/initials
Name:    George     W...    Bush
GWB
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `strlen` in the condition of the `for`-loop, it will be executed at every single step, better save the value in a variable and use the variable in the condition instead.

I would use in this case `strtok`, it deals with inputs like `Tom   marvolo riddle` where you have multiple white spaces between the names.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main(void)
{

    char line[1024];

    fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);

    char *token, *src = line;

    while(token = strtok(src, " \t"))
    {
        src = NULL; // subsequent calls of strtok must be called
                    // with NULL

        printf("%c", toupper(*token));
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

When using `strtok` you have to remember not to pass a string literal (`"this is a string literal"`) because they are read-only and `strtok` writes a `\0` at the position where the delimiter is found. If you don't know if you have write access to buffer, you have to make a copy (either in a static buffer with enough length, or use `malloc`) and then use the copy in `strtok`.

In my example I know that `line` is not a read-only variable, thus I can safely use in `strtok` (provided that I won't use it any more, otherwise a copy is required).

One problem with `strtok` is that it is not reentrant and it's better to use `strtok_r` instead.

```
char *token, *src = line, *saveptr;

while(token = strtok_r(src, " \t", &saveptr))
    ...
```

Comment: The compiler will optimize the code so that `strlen` will not be called in every loop. So it's not a real problem.

Comment: On Windows, use `strtok_s()` instead of `strtok_r()` — they are equivalent.  (An _incredibly arcane, esoteric side note_: the C standard Annex K specification of `strtok_s()` differs from both Microsoft `strtok_s()` and POSIX `strtok_r()` — fortunately, the Annex K version is almost never implemented.)

Answer (score 0):

In order to make your code work, a simple approach is to add a flag telling whether the previous character was a space. Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int wasSpace = 1;   // Add a flag.
    printf("Name: ");
    string s = get_string();

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) 
    {
        if (wasSpace && s[i] != ' ')  // Only print if previous was a space and this isn't
        {
            wasSpace = 0;
            printf("%c", toupper(s[i]));
        }
        else if (s[i] == ' ')
        {
            wasSpace = 1;    // Update the flag
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```